# parallel execution bash for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, tcpdump

i've put together a simple little bash script that iterates through 100-200+ 2GB packet captures (from daemonlogger), which prompts the user for the filter to match on in tcpdump... and then compiles all of the packets from each individual capture into 1 merged cap. One thing i've run into is i'd like for the execution to happen faster by searching multiple packet captures at once... but without just simply backgrounding with &. (tried that and it basically brought the system to its knees trying to load tons of 2GB pcaps into memory. lol oops.)  Can anyone show me how within a for-loop you can say "i want to run two or three iterations at a time for each pass." etc?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '[+] example tcp dump filters:'
echo '[+] host 1.1.1.1'
echo '[+] host 1.1.1.1 dst port 80'
echo '[+] host 1.1.1.1 and host 2.2.2.2 and dst port 80'
echo 'tcpdump filter:'
read FILTER
cd /var/packet_recorder/
DATESTAMP=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M")
# make a specific folder to drop the filtered pcaps in
mkdir /var/packet_recorder/temp/$DATESTAMP
# iterate over all pcaps and check for an instance of your filter
for file in $(ls *.pcap); do
        tcpdump -nn -A -w temp/$DATESTAMP/$file -r $file $FILTER
        # remove empty pcaps that dont match
        if [ "`ls -l temp/$DATESTAMP/$file | awk '{print $5}'`" = "24" ]; then
                rm -f "temp/$DATESTAMP/$file"
        fi
done
echo '[+] Merging pcaps'
# cd to your pcap directory 
cd /var/packet_recorder/temp/${DATESTAMP}
# merge all of the pcaps into one file and remove the seperated files
mergecap *.pcap -w merged.pcap
rm -f InternetBorder.*
echo "\[\+\] Done. your files are in $(pwd)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've learned from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219492/116972) about using [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) or `xargs -P` in [GNU Findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) for such a problem.

Using `xargs -P` (assuming there's no space in paths)

```
# iterate over all pcaps and check for an instance of your filter
# process up to 3 files at a time
ls *.pcap | xargs -n1 -P3 -I{} tcpdump -nn -A -w temp/$DATESTAMP/{} -r {} $FILTER

# remove empty pcaps that dont match (remove files whose size is 24)
wc -c temp/$DATESTAMP/*.pcap | head -n -1 |
while read size path; do
    if [[ "$size" = 24 ]]; then
        rm -f "$path"
    fi
done
```